# Using LinqPad to query a "blob" of XML

Tags: linq-to-xml, linqpad

I have some XML I need to figure out how to query with LINQ to XML. I was thinking of using LinqPad to help me figure out the syntax needed to query the specific node and attribute I was looking to access.

Does LinqPad have the ability to query just a blob of XML that I could paste from the clipboard (as long as it is well formatted)? I only see the ability to connect to databases.

If it is possible how to I enter the XML blob to be parsed by LinqPad?

Edit: I have LinqPad - Paid version - v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable with using VB, you could simply paste in your xml content into a VB expression/program. VB supports XML literals and will treat them as `XDocument`/`XElement` (depending on the existence of the xml declaration). Then you could write your queries using VB's querying syntax.

Otherwise if you would prefer C#, here's my template for how I typically work with raw XML.

```cs
// C# Program
void Main()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(XmlStr);
    // do stuff with doc
    doc.Dump(); // if you want to reformat your xml
}

string XmlStr { get; } = /* paste your xml here as an escaped string (Alt + Shift + V) */;
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQPad's connections are to data contexts. You could possibly find or write a driver for XML but it probably wouldn't even be worth looking. Just access the XML from .NET code in the script with the source as a file—or the clipboard.

LINQ to XML primarily means XDocument et al. XDocument.Load or .Parse will get you started.

Here are two ways to use LINQ to XML to query an XML schema that's on the clipboard:

```
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

// pure drilldown, step by step
XDocument.Parse(System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText())
    .Element(xsd + "schema")
    .Elements(xsd + "element")
    .Elements(xsd + "annotation")
    .Elements(xsd + "documentation")
    .Select(d => new { element = d.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name")?.Value, type = d.Parent.Parent.Attribute("type")?.Value, documentation = d?.Value})
    .Dump();

// alternative syntax, which has range variables that can be referenced in the select

(from schema in XDocument.Parse(System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText()).Elements(xsd + "schema")
from element in schema.Elements(xsd + "element")
from annotation in element.Elements(xsd + "annotation")
from documentation in annotation.Elements(xsd + "documentation")
select new {element = element.Attribute("name")?.Value, type = element.Attribute("type")?.Value, documentation?.Value})
    .Dump();
```

You can also use XPath via XPathSelectElements et al if you are familiar with that.

Note: these queries are not quite the same. The first has an item for every documentation element in the path. The second has at least one item for every schema, every element, every annotation and every documentation, regardless of having a documentation as a descendant.